# docx4j - Nodes Omitted From XmlUtils.marshalToString()

Tags: docx4j

Using `XMLUtils.marshalToString()` from docx4j, I have the following content at identical locations in two docx files (extracted from corresponding `word/document.xml` after unzipping the .docx).  These are the only differences between the files:

```
 <w:t xml:space="preserve">New line.  First is </w:t>
```

and

```
 <w:t xml:space="preserve">
 <w:r>
 <w:t xml:space="preserve">New line.</w:t>
 </w:r>
 <w:r>
 <w:t xml:space="preserve">  First is </w:t>
 </w:r>
 </w:t>
```

In the first document, the `<w:t>` node is output as above.

However, in the second, an empty `<w:t>` node is printed as follows:

```
   <w:t xml:space="preserve"></w:t>
```

I checked the `w:t` schema at http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_p-1.html and `w:r` is a valid contained element.

**Edit:** the above link is the schema of the `w:p` element, not `w:t`.  The proper link for `w:t` is: http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_t-1.html.  It clearly shows the only acceptable content for `w:t` is a string (not a `w:r` or any other tags).  Consequently (as suggested Jason's answer below), the XML from `document.xml` was invalid, and (as such) not being unmarshalled into docx4j.  As a result, the text was not available for output by XmlUtils.marshalToString().

What is keeping the second block from being output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trust marshalToString.

If it is returning an empty w:t, that's because the underlying org.docx4j.wml.Text object has a null or empty value field.

You need to look at whatever code is supposed to be populating that.

Comment: I looked at the output from where docx was read (triggered by `WordprocessingMLPackage.load`) and found this: `WARN org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler .handleEvent line 90 - [ERROR] : unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", local:"r"). Expected elements ar`.

That caused me to look again @ the link above and I've inserted the the mea culpa into the original question above.  

Short answer: the XML we're trying to read from the docx's document.xml is invalid.